# Android layout Support multiple Screens

Tags: android, xml

I know this question has been answered many times but those answers are not helping me out. My app is looking perfect on 5inch screen but on 6 inch and more the alignment is different. I have added  tag in manifest also...and also designed layout,layout-large,layout-normal also.
I want to know what is the best way to make the layout supports all screen without making 3 or 4 layouts for one screen.

Comment: create your layout views based on a ratio so it does not matter the size of the screen

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple resolutions, you may use multiple layout files, but using a single layout file makes file maintenance and management easier. When you need to modify part of the layout for different resolutions, it is good to use dimens.xml, which makes it easy to modify.

This link may help you:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=4D620DFCC329BEC0DB60E73C6B185743?v=T000000126

Answer (score 0):

sorry for answering instead of commenting but that is because of my low reputation, you can find this article helpful for you for the developers of google
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, Also this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTd7QVv7lzg

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach your problem.

**1**. You can create different XML s for a same layout based on the screen sizes like normal, 7 inch and ,for large screens  (i don't recommend this though )

A set of six generalized densities:

> ldpi (low) ~120dpi
>       enter code here
>       mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
>       hdpi (high) ~240dpi
>       xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
>       xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
>       xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

read here(how to create multiple XMLS) --> https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**2**.Give sizes based on a ratio

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
screenHeight = size.y;
screenWidth = size.x;
```

now you have values for the `screenHeight` and `screenWidth`  of that particular devise

now position layouts

eg: how to position a view as linear

```
topLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflateView.findViewById(R.id.top_len_one);
            topLinearLayout.setGravity(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            topLinearLayout.getLayoutParams().width = width;
            topLinearLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 495 * height / 1920;
```

eg: how to position a view as relative

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutForPassword = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutForPassword.setMargins(screenWidth * 240 / 1080, screenHeight * 960 / 1920, 20, 0);
    editTextPassword.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutForPassword); 

// 1080 is my default wire frame's design width , 1920 is height (in pix)
```

so its like ,
i have an image which is 1920 in height and  1820 in width 
create a layout which has 210 height in my default wire frame's design height and set resize it to my devise screen size --> 210/1920 * your devise height

this keeps the perfect ratio for any screen